# Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript

The following causes an Unexpected toeken '.' token:

```
                for (i = 0; i < numPanels.length; i++)  {
                    .fromTo(secpanpanelNo[i], duration[i], {
                        y: "0%"
                    }, {
                        y: "-100%",
                        ease: Linear.easeNone,
                        delay: delayPanels
                    },panelNo[i])
                };
```

Is there a different way to wrap this or a token pre-fix that will make this work?

The .fromTo is from Greensocks animation library.

Comment: You have to call it on an object, not on its own. JS uses `.` like many other languages; to indicate that you're calling a method or accessing a property of an object, like `someString.length` or `"1,2,3".split()`

Comment: you have `.` right after `{` (second line) what's that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `fromTo` on the `numPanels[i]` object:

```
for (i = 0; i < numPanels.length; i++)  {
  numPanels[i].fromTo(secpanpanelNo[i], duration[i], {
    y: "0%"
  }, {
    y: "-100%",
    ease: Linear.easeNone,
    delay: delayPanels
  })
};
```